# RichFaces 4.0 TagException for recursiveTreeNodesAdaptor/treeNodesAdaptor tags

Tags: exception, jsf, tags, richfaces

I am having problems when using recursiveTreeNodesAdaptor and treeNodesAdaptor in RichFaces 4.0 along with Mojarra 2.0. When I use them, I get a TagException:

> Tag
>   Library supports namespace:
>   http://richfaces.org/rich, but no tag
>   was defined for name:
>   recursiveTreeNodesAdaptor

I haven't had problems when using rich:tree or other richfaces tags.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

It has been renamed and is called treeModelRecursiveAdaptor now.

However also its functionality has been changed, so you may even have to change your backing bean code.